# Multiple spplots in a page and with a single index

Tags: r, plot, rgdal, r-sp

I have a polygon shape file named `CROPS.shp` and the following key -

```
1 - Rice
2 - Wheat 
3 - Corn 
4 - Millets
```

I read the shape file using the `rgdal` package into a variable named `my_crops`. Now `my_crops@data` has six different fields namely `Y1`, `Y2`, `Y3`, `Y4`, `Y5` and `Y6`. Each of these fields has values from 1 to 4.

So for example, the first few rows of `crops@data` would be like

```
Y1   Y2   Y3   Y4   Y5    Y6 
1    2    4    1    1    2
3    4    1    1    1    2
4    2    2    2    1    3
```

**What do I want to do?**

I want to have a page with 6 plots (2 rows, 3 columns), where the first plot would be based on the field `Y1`, and the last plot would be based on the field `Y6`. The colour of the plots (polygon shapes) should be based on the values 1 to 4, in each of the shapefile plots.

The plots should be accompanied by a single legend at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(maptools)
nc.sids <- readShapePoly(system.file("etc/shapes/sids.shp", package="spdep")[1],
  ID="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))

set.seed(1)
nc.sids$a = factor(sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace=T))
nc.sids$b = factor(sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace=T))
nc.sids$c = factor(sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace=T))
nc.sids$d = factor(sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace=T))
nc.sids$e = factor(sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace=T))
nc.sids$f = factor(sample(letters[1:4], 100, replace=T))
spplot(nc.sids[c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")], 
    colorkey = list(space = "bottom"), layout = c(3, 2),
    as.table = TRUE)
```

[image]